# ssh-keygen wont work

Tags: linux, login, ssh-agent, ssh-keys

For CentOs I am trying to configure a ssh key but it denies the approval. I tried this from the following link: http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html

For more details I raised the same question on server fault: 
"[ssh-keygen problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/200708/ssh-keygen-problem)"

Please let me know any alternatives.

Comment: "Denies the approval"?

Comment: Yes i meant it would prompt for the password inspite the key is set

Answer (score 1):

If it is asking for a "password" your SSH server isn't configured correctly.

If it is asking for a "passphrase" then this is working as intended, if you don't want to have to enter a passphrase while using keys then do not enter a passphrase when creating the key.

Not using a passphrase is a security issue, you should think about your servers situation (importance of what it does, who may be able to access it, etc) before proceeding without a passphrase.